# variable as index in an associative array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I'm trying to create an associative array, create an empty array, and then add a (`indexName` -> value) pair:

```
var arrayName = new Array;

arrayName["indexName"] = value;

// i know i can also do the last line like this:

arrayName.indexName = value;
```

When I assign the value to the `indexName` I want `indexName` to be dynamic and the value of a variable. So I tried this:

```
arrayName[eval("nume")] = value;
```

Where:

```
var var1 = "index";
var var2 = "Name";

var nume = '"' + var1 + var2 + '"';
```

but: `alert(arrayName["indexName"]);` doesn't return "value"... it says "undefined"

Is there something I’m missing? (I’m not familiar with `eval()` ); if the way I’m trying is a dead end, is there another way to make the index name of the associative array value dynamic?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

At first I don't think you need a real array object to do what you need, you can use a plain object.

You can simply use the bracket notation to access a property, using the value of a variable:

```
var obj = {};
var nume = var1 + var2;
obj[nume] = value;
```

Array's are simply objects, the concept of an "associative array" can be achieved by using a simple object, objects are collections of properties that contain values.

True arrays are useful when you need to store numeric indexes, they automatically update their `length` property when you assign an index or you `push` a value to it.

Comment: thank you...arrays introduced some complications with quotes inside square brackets

Answer (score 7):

You would use objects to do that:

```
var hash = {}
hash["foo"] = "foo";
hash.bar    = "bar";
// This is the dynamic approach: Your key is a string:
baz         = "baz"
hash[baz]   = "hello";
```

To iterate, just use a `for` loop or `$.each()` in jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

use `arrayName[var1+var2]`

Note that `arrayName.var` is the same as `arrayName["var"]` -- it's just syntactic sugar. The second form is mostly used when dealing with the kind of problems that you are facing - dynamic object keys, and keys that are not alphanumeric (think of `arrayName[".eval()"]`; this is a perfectly legal object key that has nothing to do with the javascript `eval()` function)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `variableName = 'bla'+'foo'; arrayRef[variableName] = 'something';` ?

And even so, you should use an object literal instead. `x = {}; x[variablename] = 'blah';`

Answer (score 0):

You want a plain object with the same [bracket notaiton](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) here, like this:

```
var arrayName = {};
arrayName["indexName"] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there was no need for an array object, a simple object did the job; further more an array introduced the need to use quotes inside the square brackets `obj["var1 + var2"]` to access the object property's value and not the value associated with an index (i think); the quotes transformed `"var1 + var2"` into a string. Using a simple object eliminated the need for quotes, so I can use `obj[var1 + var2]`, wich worked :)

Thanks everyone !

Comment: No, you don't need to use quotes inside the brackets. If you use quotes you get the literal string `"var1 + var2"` and not the values of `var1` and `var2`.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like like following;

```
let parentArray = [];
let childArray = [1, 2, 3];
childArray.name = 'my-array-1';
parentArray.push(childArray);
```

To access that by name in ES6;

```
parentArray.filter(x => x.name == 'my-array-1');
```