# Filtering two-dimensional javascript array based on 1st index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following javascript array code which defines some items:

```
product[17564] =    Array;
product[17564][1245] = ['BL-2810', 'text1']; 
product[17564][1246] = ['BL2810AB', 'text2']; 
product[17564][1247] = ['BL2810AN', 'text3']; 

product[17563] =    Array;
product[17563][1238] = ['BK-2810', 'text4']; 
product[17563][1239] = ['BK2810AB', 'text5']; 

product[17565] =    Array;
product[17565][1253] = ['CK-2810', 'text6']; 
product[17565][1254] = ['CK2810AN', 'text7'];
```

and I want to filter the items, based on the 1st index of the 'product' array, which is set dynamically by the user. For example, if the user set number is '17563', then I want to filter the following items which have '17563' as their 1st index:

```
product[17563][1238]
product[17563][1239]
```

and use only those items on a code that follows.
Thanks.

Comment: That code is not doing what you think it is. Instead of setting things to "Array", set them to `[]`.

Comment: You should use objects instead of arrays. And what is your problem? How to access a property/index with a variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [variable as index in an associative array - Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091257/variable-as-index-in-an-associative-array-javascript)

Comment: I'm not sure how the result has to be structured, but won't `product[number]` give the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have product categories and in each category you have some products.

It also looks like the categories and the products have a kind of id, that you are using as the array index.

I think you are not using the correct data structure to store the data.

What happens if you have only 3 categories with ids 17883, 17884 and 17885?
You will end with an array of 17886 (counting position 0) positions just to use 3 of them.

What you have to do is a object that stores category information and product information and then fill the array with these objects.

For example:

```
var categories = new Array();

var category1 = new Object();
category1.id = 17883;
category1.products = new Array();
categories[0] = category1;

var product1 = new Object();
product1.id = 1233;
product1.code = 'BK-404';
product1.name = 'text3';

category1.products[0] = product1;
// and so on
```

To read the information you would do:

```
var userInput = //receive user input
for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
    if(categories[i].id == userInput){
        return categories[i].products;
    }
    return null; //category not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, it gave me the clue to use json objects. Actually I have product data and some variants that each product has, with attributes (ie, similar logic to categories and products with attributes, as in the answer).

Eventually I json encoded my initial php array ('$array') from which I get the data,

```
$array_json=json_encode($array);
```

and passed it to javascript (this was done through smarty, because I use smarty templates in my application).

```
$smarty->assign('array_json', $array_json);
```

Then in the smarty template file, I created a javascript array out of the smarty array:

```
var prd_array={$array_json};
```

and continued with:

```
for (var product_id in prd_array) {
            if(product_id == id) {
                for (var variant_id in prd_array[product_id]) {                     
                    for (var some_attribute_id in prd_array[product_id][variant_id].attributes)     {                           
                        var variant_title = prd_array[product_id][variant_id].attributes[some_attribute_id].attribute_name;                         
                        document.myfrm.myselect.options[document.myfrm.myselect.options.length]=new Option("variant_title, variant_id, true, false);                             
                    }
                }
                break;
            }               
        }
```

To explain the above, I iterated with nested loops to the deeper levels of the multidimensional array in order to get some attribute value of the variants of the selected product by the user. `'id'` is the selected product id value by the user, which is compared against every `product_id` value and when matched, the variants of the specific product are iterated, along with their `atttributes` property, which always has a single element with index `some_attribute_id`, and one of it's properties is `attribute_name` which is one of the values to be used for displaying in a dynamically populated select menu (along with the `variant_id` value).